# OpenTelemetry not logging messages with exception details to Application Insights from python code

Tags: python, azure, logging, azure-application-insights, open-telemetry

I am in process of migrating a python 3.10 project from OpenCensus to OpenTelemetry as the former is being [sunsetted this year](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-monitor/app/opentelemetry-python-opencensus-migrate?tabs=python).

The logs are working correctly for standard `info`, `warning`, `error`, etc logging but I am having an issue with logging `exceptions`.

Take the following example code:

```
from azure.monitor.opentelemetry import configure_azure_monitor
import logging

configure_azure_monitor(
     connection_string="MY_APPINSIGHTS_CONNECTION_STRING",
)

try:
    logging.info("My INFO message")
    logging.warning("My WARNING message")
    logging.error("My ERROR message")
    raise Exception("My EXCEPTION message")
except Exception:
    logging.exception('My CUSTOM message')
    logging.error('My CUSTOM message', stack_info=True, exc_info=True)
```

The logs before the exception is raised work as expected. What for the logs in the except block is that an Application insights log would be created with an `outerMessage` or `details..message` of "*My CUSTOM message*" or at least "*My CUSTOM message*" somewhere in the record. What I am seeing when I check though is the following:

```
exceptions
| order by timestamp desc
```

[image]

"*My CUSTOM message*" is nowhere to be found. Is there a configuration option I can set so that I get the custom error message? Note I get the exact same log for the following two lines:

```
logging.exception('My CUSTOM message')
logging.error('My CUSTOM message', stack_info=True, exc_info=True)
```

This behaviour is different from the old OpenCensus behaviour which did log the custom message within the record along with the exception data.

Answer (score 0):

It is expected behavior using opentelemetry you will get onlt the exceptions which are raised like below:

```
import logging
from opentelemetry.sdk._logs.export import BatchLogRecordProcessor
from azure.monitor.opentelemetry.exporter import AzureMonitorLogExporter

from opentelemetry._logs import (
    get_logger_provider,
    set_logger_provider,
)
from opentelemetry.sdk._logs import (
    LoggerProvider,
    LoggingHandler,
)
set_logger_provider(LoggerProvider())
exporter = AzureMonitorLogExporter(
    connection_string="InstrumentationKey=d1079;IngestionEndpoint=https://centralindia-0.in.applicationinsights.azure.com/;LiveEndpoint=https://centralindia.livediagnostics.monitor.azure.com/"
)
get_logger_provider().add_log_record_processor(BatchLogRecordProcessor(exporter))

rith_handler = LoggingHandler()
rith_logger = logging.getLogger(__name__)
rith_logger.addHandler(rith_handler)
rith_logger.setLevel(logging.INFO)

try:
    rith_logger.info("Rithwik INFO message")
    rith_logger.warning("Rithwik WARNING message")
    rith_logger.error("Rithwik ERROR message")
    raise Exception("Rithwik Exception")
except Exception as e:
    rith_logger.error(f'Rithwik custom error: {e}')
```

[image]

Error message after raise as below:

[image]

custom exception using logging exception gives `exception` as message   as below  not the custom message:

```
import logging
from opentelemetry.sdk._logs.export import BatchLogRecordProcessor
from azure.monitor.opentelemetry.exporter import AzureMonitorLogExporter

from opentelemetry._logs import (
    get_logger_provider,
    set_logger_provider,
)
from opentelemetry.sdk._logs import (
    LoggerProvider,
    LoggingHandler,
)
set_logger_provider(LoggerProvider())
exporter = AzureMonitorLogExporter(
    connection_string="InstrumentationKey=d19b79;IngestionEndpoint=https://centralindia-0.in.applicationinsights.azure.com/;LiveEndpoint=https://centralindia.livediagnostics.monitor.azure.com/"
)
get_logger_provider().add_log_record_processor(BatchLogRecordProcessor(exporter))

rith_handler = LoggingHandler()
rith_logger = logging.getLogger(__name__)
rith_logger.addHandler(rith_handler)
rith_logger.setLevel(logging.INFO)

rith_logger.info("Rithwik INFO message")
rith_logger.warning("Rithwik WARNING message")
rith_logger.error("Rithwik ERROR message")
rith_logger.exception(f'Rithwik custom error: ')
```

[image]

To get the custom message you one have to use raise .

Comment: Thank you for the response, it seems very odd to me that `logging.exception("Something")` will not create a log record containing "Something"

Comment: Yeah, it doesnot log this .